# CodeIgniter Custom Function Placement Advice

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, helper

Outside of CodeIgniter I've created a function that takes a url as a parameter, processes it within a series of other functions and conditions and either returns an error message or array of image width and heights.

Being new to CodeIgniter, I'm trying to bring this into my CodeIgniter installation but I'm not sure where to place this functions. Should I place them in a helper, a library or even process it through my model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe make it a library. Although it is just my preference.

I don't see much difference between helper and library except from the structure. May be some other can put more light on it.